# How to delete system.profile collection from a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, profiling

I am profiling the db queries in MongoDB. I followed [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/) link. I am trying to delete all data from the collection system.profile so I can start benchmarking different queries again. I tried the following code but it gives an error

**CONSOLE SYNTAX**

```
> db.system.profile.remove({})
```

**ERROR**

```
cannot delete from system namespace
```

How do I delete all data from that collection? If that's not possible, how can I start profiling from the beginning?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Firstly, turn off the profiling by setting its level to 0.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
```

Then you can simply drop the collection.

```
db.system.profile.drop()
```

Now you are free to go and start it all over.

Answer (score 25):

To riff off of the accepted answer, it is at times helpful to do in a single line:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0); db.system.profile.drop(); db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

I'm also finding that setting the size of system.profile to 10MB (or larger) rather than its default 1MB is quite helpful:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0); db.system.profile.drop(); db.createCollection("system.profile", {capped: true, size: 10 * 1024 * 1024}); db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the profile collection is **capped**!

In order to create a collection keeping more records about queries, recreate it with a desired size.

```sh
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
db.system.profile.drop()
db.createCollection( "system.profile", { capped: true, size: 1024*1024*10 } )
db.setProfilingLevel(1, { slowms: 500 })
```